# how to migrate custom code from magento 1.9.2 to magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, module, migration, magento-1.9.2.0, magento-2.1

I have created custom modules in Magento 1.9.2,Now I am moving into Magento 2.1. So I need to **transfer custom code from Magento 1.9.2 to Magento 2.1.**
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Magento 2 migration tool (full guide available here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html) does not migrate custom modules and 3rd party extensions automatically.

You will have to **manually create your custom modules and upgrade your Magento 1 3rd party extensions to their Magento 2 upgraded versions (if there's one available).**

I suggest you have a look at the official code migration to help you: https://github.com/magento/code-migration

Comment: Thank you for your answer Can you please tell me how can i change my custom module from magento1.9.2 to magento 2.1 .Do i have to write separate files for every custom controller Action .or any further changes with file structure.Since I am new in magento 2 development.

Comment: @Tush see my updated answer

Comment: why code migration is missing here?  https://github.com/magento/code-migration